# Console.log() appearing in web browser console, but not in Android Studio console when debugging ionic app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to debug my ionic app on an Android device.

I am using `console.log()` to display an array:

```
console.log("List of recipes: " + this.recipes);
```

When I run the app in the web browser (`ionic serve`), "List of recipes" is logged to the console, & displays the array.

However, when I run this on my Android device (`ionic capacitor android run -l`), "List of recipes" is logged, but the array isn't.

Can someone please tell me why the array is printed out in the browser console, but not in the Android Studio console?

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Comment: Hi @RichardDapice, it's an Ionic & Angular app, so Typescript

Answer (score 9):

You can see the outputs on browser console.

Try this:

1. Connect your device to your computer
2. Run `adb devices` in command prompt/console
3. Run Google Chrome and type "chrome://inspect/#devices" .
4. Choose "inspect" for your app.

Comment: Now I am getting this error message: `I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;`

Answer (score 5):

I found this too, so I just use JSON.stringify to display objects and arrays e.g.

console.log("List of recipes: " + JSON.stringify(this.recipes));